# Using blend tool for logo design in Ilustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

is this a problem if I use blend tool to create a shape with a structure and gradient I want in a logo - if I expand, it doesn't look how I want it to look.

I was wondering if there are technical problems with blend tool shapes in logo design. Or "vector is vector" and I shouldn't worry? I don't mean problems like, how to do monochromatic or inversed version - more like if the number of steps used in bled option matter and stuff like that, more connected to the complexity of a shape itself and then printing it/putting it on web.

Right one is a mountain made with blend tool, and on the left is the one I expanded. Would you guys recommend to recreate the "rough edges" and those gradients myself without using the bled tool then?

[image]
Thanks!

Comment: I would be more worried about why it does not expand. Since that is indeed weird, and does indicate you have a problem. OTOH it may be just a effect on group thing.

Comment: I agree with @joojaa -- I'd worry that expanding it changes the appearance. Because, upon output, it will be flattened and generally expanded.

Comment: the issue Is that thanks to blend tool I got a nice texture to the object and this is something  I am not sure I will be able to replicate without it - but thanks for your tips, It seems that due to technical reasons I will need to.

Answer (score 2):

The primary issue you will face by leaving a blend "live" will be output and compatibility. While it is always fine within Illustrator itself. Logo use doesn't stay strictly within Illustrator.

For a *logo*, there are typically hundreds of different uses. Upon output a blend **is** essentially expanded and flattened. So, if you are seeing an appearance change when you expand the blend, that's *not* a good thing. That change could possibly happen *anywhere* the logo is output. Imagine embroidery, or signage, or engraving... typically requiring legacy file formats. Sometimes flat legacy formats (AI8).... those will expand and flatten blends.

A better alternative would be to expand the blend then adjust appearance if necessary. I find for *logos* delivering the simplest form of the artwork is best in order to ensure there are no output problems for myriad uses.

Comment: good thing is I know how the logo will be used mostly: web + some small print forms eg. business cards + jobs. 

As I export it as .png/.jpg I see no issues, it looks great. Though when I use "Expand Appearance" option in Illustrator, everything goes super flat.

Comment: errr.. just because a logo is used today on a website and stationary, that does not mean next year they won't want signs, caps, mugs, tote bags, pens, etc.. `:)` For a logo, it's kind of short-sighted to not think about long-term usage. -- I don't know what "super flat" means so I can't really help with that. If you were to edit your question and add a couple images, before and after, there may be a solution. Clearly a png/jpg is a poor format for most logo usage - again, it may solve a problem today, but it won't help 3 or 6 months from now when they want other items.

Comment: sure, I get it. I was just encouraged when I saw some tutorials for logos designed with blend tool, but no one there actually spoke about exporting it for further uses, so I was quite reckless not to check it before I started creating. I'll add a screenshot in a moment.

Comment: Scott, are those images of any help?

Comment: The only real difference I see is the very rough edge of the blend. Is that what you are trying to retain?

Comment: Yup, this is what I wanted to retain as it looks less artifical than the straight one. I redone it with a mesh tool and it looks pretty ok.